# MIPS assembly - random integer range

Tags: assembly, mips, random

Hello im trying to use random integer range and the values that i get is out ouf the ones that i set.

for example:

```
sw $a0, 0($s0)  
li $a0, 1000
li $a1, 3500
li $v0, 42   #random
```

So i just want it to be random numbers between 1000-3500 but it gives me any random number.

Can you please help me to understand where my mistake is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$a0` is the random seed, not the lower bound.  You should set `$a1` to `2501` to generate 0-2500 random number, and add 1000 to the result.

```
sw $a0, 0($s0)  
li $a1, 2501
li $v0, 42   #random
add $a0, $a0, 1000
```

Comment: btw, the `42` syscall may not be available on your simulator. check its manual.