# MIPS printing number randomly

Tags: mips

I need to code a simple memorization game using MIPS . The game starts by randomly printing a number between 10-99 on the screen,then ask the user to enter the exact number.
How can that be done using MIPS ?

Comment: Is this a homework question? Which part are you having trouble with? (e.g. random number generation, getting user input)

Comment: Yes,random number generation and comparing the number with the number entered by the user so the game can be continued if it's corrrect

Comment: Beau Grantham , not yet but I have some ideas,but I can't get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already some similar questions on SO:

[Generating random numbers using a syscall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394537/random-numbers-in-mips)

[MIPS assembly - random integer range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103766/mips-assembly-random-integer-range)

Have a look at those, your textbook, and possibly some online tutorials. Most importantly: give it a go yourself; that's the only way you'll get better at it.